# JS ECMA6 - Ternary Operator for backwards compatibility

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

I have a piece of javascript code that uses the ECMA6 dataset property to access an objects `data-foo` attribute of an element `e`. Unfortunately, this is not compatable with <=IE10. To combat this, I've rewritten my code to using a ternary operator, using dataset when supported and getAttribute when not:

```
(e.dataset) ? e.dataset.foo : e.getAttribute('data-foo');
```

But why shouldn't I just replace the entire line with `e.getAttribute('data-foo')`? What is the real benefit of using ECMA6 standards when previous standards are just as good and more widely supported?

Comment: DOM =/= Ecmascript. datasets belong to HTML5 and have nothing to do with Javascript spec. The difference is that dataset is a proprerty of the object HTMLElement, while an attribute is a HTML attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `dataset` property doesn't seem to be part of ES6 spec. It is part of [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Coming to your question,

> What is the real benefit of using ECMA6 standards when previous standards are just as good and more widely supported?

Simplicity.

As you may observe, among the two approaches, `e.dataset.foo` and `e.getAttribute('data-foo')`, the former is less verbose, and hence desirable in many cases. For one, it reduces the size of Javascript files you ship.

The spec even highlights the point:

> The dataset IDL attribute provides **convenient** accessors for all the data-* attributes on an element. ...
>
> [Emphasis mine]

Comment: Coming back to this after a few months later, I realised that this only partly answers my question - I understand that smaller and easier to read code should always be the goal, but the other half of my question should be 'why should I use modern code with a fallback to older code, instead of just using the older code only'